# Python if statement confusion

Tags: python, if-statement

Neewbie here. I'm doing CS50p and found myself confused about one of first problem sets.

> In deep.py, implement a program that prompts the user for the answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything, outputting Yes if the user inputs 42 or (case-insensitively) forty-two or forty two. Otherwise output No.

So I made this:

```
answ = input("What is Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything? ")

if answ == "42" or "forty two" or "forty-two":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

But output is always "yes".

However if I slice it like that:

```
answ = input("What is Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything? ")

if answ == "42":
    print("Yes")
elif answ == "forty-two":
    print("Yes")
elif answ == "forty two":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

It works.

Much thanks for simple answere.

Comment: that's not how logical operators work. you either want `if answ == "42" or answ  == "forty two" or answ == "forty-two":`  or even better `if answ in ("42", "forty two", "forty-two"):`

Answer (score 1):

You are so close but you just have to add in the call for answ within the or clause every time

```
answ = input("What is Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything? ")

if answ == "42" or answ == "forty two" or answ == "forty-two":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first implementation is the condition in the if statement. The condition `answ == "42" or "forty two" or "forty-two"` is always `True` because the expression `"forty two" or "forty-two"` is always `True`, as the string `"forty two"` is considered a truthy value in python.